# Merging two dataset

Tags: oracle, delphi, merge, dataset, dao

I have one "big" `TOracleDataSet` which I can't change 'cause it's using in many different parts of huge project. I want to add just one record to this dataset for using in another grid. The solve way I see it is create another one oracle data set which will combine wanted record and another ones from "big" dataset. In other words, "small" dataset includes "big" dataset.

Comment: Use a view that does a join combining the data your need and link a Delphi Tdataset to that.

Comment: That's not exactly I need. I should use first, "big", dataset. If SQL text has changed in "big" dataset it shoould reflect "small" dataset and change it too.

Comment: I would still use a view, But you need to put an example in your question, because maybe I'm getting you all wrong.

Comment: @Johan Unfourntunately, I wouldn't go to DB structure changes.

Comment: unfortunatly as your question now stands I have no idea what the actual question **is**

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation and my english.Basically I have a dataset that handles data that consists of a low of records (about 500 thousands).It uses a complicated SQL code for retrieving that data and this SQL code may be changed in future.Actually I need another dataset that will has 500001 records(500 thousands from first dataset and one new record).The idea is new dataset will has its own record and will include another 500 thousands from first dataset.Finally it's necessary to link first dataset to second and therefore first dataset will be changed, second dataset will change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe?

[TxQuery Project](https://code.google.com/p/txquery/)

This was a commercial project at one time, but the auther was convinced to release it opensource.

> TxQuery component is a TDataSet descendant component that can be used to query one or more TDataSet descendant components using SQL statements. It is implemented in Delphi 100% source code, no DLL required, because it implements its own SQL syntax parser and SQL engine.

That quote was taken from the page of the current maintainer, I believe, [Chau Chee Yang](http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2009/12/txquery-20.html)  .

Either this or maybe TClientDataset might be your best options.

Comment: THanks for your response. What's the way you see in using TClientDataSet?

Comment: If you can load the data from the Oracle dataset into the TClientDataSet then You can manipulate it away from the oracle database connection, including inserting a record.  Admittedly I don't use TClientDataset and it would be better to hear from someone who does use it, but I would think it should be possible.